# Why can I only run Hamster Time Tracker as root?

Tags: permissions, hamster

I've installed Project Hamster from source with:

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/hamster-applet
cd hamster-applet
./waf configure build --prefix=/usr
sudo ./waf install
```

Attempting to run it as myself gives the following output:

```
~$ hamster-time-tracker                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hamster-time-tracker", line 591, in <module>
    from hamster.configuration import runtime, dialogs, conf, load_ui_file
  File "/home/michael-robinson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hamster/configuration.py", line 79, in
 <module>
    runtime = RuntimeStore()
  File "/home/michael-robinson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hamster/configuration.py", line 69, in
 __init__
    self.storage = Storage()
  File "/home/michael-robinson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hamster/client.py", line 69, in __init
__
    self.bus = dbus.SessionBus()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 211, in __new__
    mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 100, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbu
s-wLzO4gfRbJ: Connection refused
```

It runs OK as root:

```
~$ sudo hamster-time-tracker
```

How might I be able to modify my Hamster installation so I can run it as a normal user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you weren't `su`'d in, and/or didn't use `sudo` with any of the other pre-installation commands? Because it works perfectly for me as a normal user when built in the following manner:

```
izx@ppauvm:~/src$ sudo apt-get build-dep hamster-applet
git clone git://git.gnome.org/hamster-applet
cd hamster-applet
./waf configure build --prefix=/usr
sudo ./waf install
hamster-time-tracker
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I deleted every trace of Hamster from my system and re-tried, I must have done as you suggested at some point.